# How the booking system works in expressionengine?

Tags: freeform

Suggest any plugin used for the booking process using freeform entries.
How the booking process works for expression engine as it works for word-press website?(any rental booking website).
I just want the same flow for my site (using expression engine).
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hi,
I am using the freeform for creating the forms for adding rental purpose. So that how can I use this for booking? Just like any wordpress website used for booking rental purpose.